# Disposing a connection that returns a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using `Renci.SshNet.Sftp` to make a connection to an SFTP server.  Once connected, I am returning an `SftpFileStream` of a file found on the server to an action of my controller.  The controller actually sends a reader of the `SftpFileStream` to a service method which parses the stream and does what it needs to with the information.

Here is the question...

When instantiating a new `SftpClient`, one should use the `using` keyword to ensure that the connection is disposed of.  However, if I do that, then the `SftpClient` gets disposed before the file can be parsed.  To fix this, I remove the `using` statement, and all is well.  But then I have no way of disposing the `SftpClient`.  So what to do?

Here is some code...

Connection Service:

```
public class SFTPConnectionService
{
    public SftpFileStream GetRemoteFile(string filename)
    {
        // Server credentials
        var host = "host";
        var port = 22;
        var username = "username";
        var password = "password";

        var sftp = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password);

        // Connect to the SFTP server
        sftp.Connect();

        // Read the file in question
        var file = sftp.OpenRead(filename);

        return file;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class RemoteFileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SFTP()
    {
        var sftpService = new SFTPConnectionService();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(sftpService.GetRemoteFile(@"path/filename.txt")))
        {
            // Do whatever with the file

            return View("View", ViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

So I am using a `using` block around the `StreamReader` that reads the file, so that will be disposed of, but that still leaves the `SftpClient` that needs to be disposed of.

I had thought about copying the `SftpFileStream` to another stream, and returning that so that I could wrap the `SftpClient` in a `using` block, but that seems like a bad idea already, and I also don't know how big the file is, so I really want to stream it from the SFTP server instead of copying it all into memory.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: Have `SFTPConnectionService` implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: If `SFTPConnectionService` implements `IDisposable`, how would I dispose of the connection made from within a method of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really want to stream it from the SFTP server instead of copying it all into memory

Well it's all going to get into memory anyway when it gets added to the ViewModel.  Here's a few options:

- Wrap the stream in a class that implements `IDisposable` and is responsible for disposing of the stream *and* the client.
- Don't return a stream but rather return the data from it.  Then you can dispose of the stream and the client together.

If you want to make `SFTPConnectionService` implement `IDisposable` then you would do something like this:

- Add class properties for the `SFTPConnectionService` and `StreamReader`
- Add a `Dispose` method to `SFTPConnectionService` that calls `Dispose` on each of them

Something like this:

```
public class SFTPConnectionService : IDisposable
{

    private SftpClient sftp;
    private SftpFileStream file;

    public SftpFileStream GetRemoteFile(string filename)
    {
        // Server credentials
        var host = "host";
        var port = 22;
        var username = "username";
        var password = "password";

        sftp = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password);

        // Connect to the SFTP server
        sftp.Connect();

        // Read the file in question
        file = sftp.OpenRead(filename);

        return file;
    }

    // Recommended implementation of IDisposable:
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        // Use SupressFinalize in case a subclass 
        // of this type implements a finalizer.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);   
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing) 
            {
                if(sftp != null)
                     sftp.Dispose();
                if(file != null)
                     file.Dispose();
            }

            // Indicate that the instance has been disposed.
            _disposed = true;   
        }
    }
}
```

your calling code would then be

```
using(var sftpService = new SFTPConnectionService())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(sftpService.GetRemoteFile(@"path/filename.txt")))
{
        // Do whatever with the file

        return View("View", ViewModel);
}
```

Comment: The `StreamReader` in the controller actually passes the stream to another method in another class.  That method parses the file line by line, extracts only what is needed, and returns that back to the controller in the form of a ViewModel.  Based on yours and Jasen's comment, it looks like implementing `IDisposable` in the `SFTPConnectionService` is a good solution, but I'm unsure how to go about doing that.

Comment: You rock.  Thanks a lot!